# How to update my progress bar dynamically with my function?

Tags: .net, vb.net, progress-bar

I have a function which previews a report at the end of it. It takes a few minutes since the data that is retrieved from the database is pretty huge. Hence I need a progress bar. Now i need the progress bar to update and end with the function dynamically. How can i do it? any kind of help will be appreciated. My code is as below.

**On button click event**

```
Backgroundworker1.RunworkerAsync()
```

**On BackgroundWorker1.DoWork event**

```
ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
ProgressBar1.Step=1

ProgressBar1.PerformStep

If chkInvRef.Checked= True Then
 AccountLedgerReportWithRef()
Else
AccountLedgerReport()
EndIf
```

My progress bar does not seem to move. It gets blocked after first block. My report gets previewed but the progress bar does not move ahead. Kindly help.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: First things first, do not do ANYTHING related to the UI in the `DoWork` event handler of a `BackgroundWorker`. The whole point of that event is to do background work.  Anything to do with the UI is the definition of foreground work.  If you're going to use a `BackgroundWorker` then please do some reading on how it works.  Try [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?471889-Using-the-BackgroundWorker-Component).

Comment: As for progress, a lot of people seem to think that it is magic. If you want to be able to display progress then you have to be able to calculate progress. If you are calling a method and it blocks until it completes then there's no way you can possibly know where it's up to so you can't tell the user. You need to first determine whether it's possible to calculate progress during the operation and then, if it is, you need to calculate it at appropriate points and then report it as demonstrated in my link above.

Comment: ok. got it. can u guide me how do i go about with my code? can u give me some kinda idea??? some small code snippet or smthing? i viisted the link that u've posted but it aint of any help for my case.

Comment: Show the code for the AccountLedger methods so we can see if they are appropriate for reporting progress or not.

Comment: We can only help you if you show us code for your `AccountLedgerReportWithRef` and `AccountLedgerReport` functions. Do you have any loop in there? Yes: You can report progress.

Comment: The link I posted **IS** of help in your case because it shows you how to report progress when using a `BackgroundWorker`. It can't be of help in your calculating progress because we have no idea what the actual work you're doing is. You do though, so how can you write the code and not have any idea of whether you can know where it's up to and, if you can, how to calculate it?